# Prolog How can I construct a list of list into a single list by interleaving?

Tags: list, prolog, interleave

How can I construct a list of a list into one single list with interleaving sublists?
like recons([[1,2],[3,4]],X) will give X= [1,3,2,4]?
I have been trying hours and my code always gave me very strange results or infinite loop,
what I thinking was something like this:

```
recons([[A|R],REST],List):-
    recons(R,REST),
    append(A,[R|REST],List).
```

I know its completely wrong, but I don`t know how to fix this.

Comment: It it always nested two levels deep? Or can this be arbitrary deep?

Comment: Furthermore an advice I have to give very often lately: try *rubber duck debugging*: explain to your rubber duck why you think this approach should work, try to convince your rubber duck. Usually you will start to see problems, and after a few iterations, you can come up with a solution.

Comment: It is possible deeper, like ([[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]],X) will possibly return [1,2,3,4,5,6]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of thinking about efficiency first, we can think about correctness first of all.

```erlang
interleaving_join( [[]|X], Y):- 
    interleaving_join( X,  Y).
```

that much is clear, but what else?

```erlang
interleaving_join( [[H|T]|X],         [H|Y]):- 
               append(    X, [T], X2),
               interleaving_join( X2,    Y).
```

But when does it end? When there's nothing more there:

```erlang
interleaving_join( [], []).
```

Indeed,

```erlang
2 ?- interleaving_join([[1,2],[3,4]], Y).
Y = [1, 3, 2, 4] ;
false.

4 ?- interleaving_join([[1,4],[2,5],[3,6,7]], X).
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] ;
false.
```

This assumes we only want to join the lists inside the list, whatever the elements are, like `[[...],[...]] --> [...]`. In particular, we don't care whether the elements might themselves be lists, or not.

It might sometimes be interesting to collect all the non-list elements in the inner lists, however deeply nested, into one list (without nesting structure). In fact such lists are actually trees, and that is known as *flattening*, or collecting the tree's *fringe*. It is a different problem.